# How to go on previous address if i opened page in new tab or directly accessed

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies

I have results page like

```
http://www.test.com/search
```

and search results data like this

```
http://www.test.com/search/a
http://www.test.com/search/b
http://www.test.com/search/c
```

Now what i want, if i am accessing page http://www.test.com/search/a directly in browsers address bar then back to previous link should refer to http://www.test.com/search

Even if i opened search results page http://www.test.com/search/a to new tab then it should also refer to http://www.test.com/search on click back to previous link

Note : javascript:history.go(-1) not working in this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully this is not possible to do. If every site had the ability to hijack the browsers' back and forward buttons the internet would be a pretty horrible place. It is in fact a security feature that the browser does not let you do this.

I cannot even think of an end to which such a means would be required, however if reaching `/search` is so important to the navigation/ux then simply route the user to `/search` by default unless they've submitted a query from there.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for Browser Back and Forward Button. As they will be disabled in case you enter url or open in new tab/window. However you can place back button/link on page itself which can redirect to  previous page url.

```
<a href="/search" >Back</a>
```

Also you can choose to close window after clicking like

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;" >Back</a>
```

Comment: is it not possible even using cookies ?

Comment: No, I afraid cookie also just part of programmable approach. While back/forward button disaple/enable  handled by browser itself (Unless some api is available from browser of course ).